# R - Installing package with remotes::install_github ask for higher version of the dependencies which BiocManager::install() can not find

Tags: r, install.packages

I need to install few packages that should be installed with remotes::install_github()  like

*"acidgenomics/basejump"*   or   *"satijalab/seurat"*.

During the installation, it need to upgrade few other packages version. The BiocManager::install program cannot find those versions and I had to install those dependencies packages version with:

```
R CMD INSTALL IRanges_2.20.2.tar.gz
```

Then other packages, that use the same packages stop working.  like *DESeq2*, 
I get the error:

```
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘DESeq2’:
 objects ‘rowSums’, ‘colSums’, ‘rowMeans’, ‘colMeans’ are not exported by 'namespace:S4Vectors'
```

I found few answers that say it happen (like [url](https://github.com/Bioconductor/genefilter/issues/3))

> remotes::install_github() isn't picking up the correct Bioconductor
>   devel repos, whereas installing with BiocManager::install() does work
>   as expected.

we have the R 3.6.0 installed as a module and a lot of users uses the same R version. I need all packages to work for everyone.

How can I make all variety  packages versions to work?

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I install new version of R 3.6.3 with Bioconductor 3.10 and all the packages install right.